# A graph G is edge reconstructible if $m\gt \frac12{n\choose 2}$

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove: A graph G is edge reconstructible if $m\gt \frac12{n\choose 2}$,
> where $m$ is $G$'s size and $n$ is $G$'s order.

A graph is edge-reconstructible if it can be reconstructed up to isomorphism
from its edge-deleted subgraphs.
The above question should be reduced from the following theorem.

> A graph $G$ is edge reconstructible if there exists a spanning
> subgraph $F$ of $G$ such that either of the following two conditions
> holds.
> (i) $|G\rightarrow H|_F$ takes the same value for all edge
> reconstructions $H$ of $G$,
> (ii) $|F\rightarrow G|\lt2^{e(G)−e(F)−1}|\operatorname{Aut}(G)|$.

I should use (ii) to prove, but I cannot find a suitable subgraph $F$.

Comment: What is the
 question?

Comment: I'm sorry. The title is the question. I edited.